# jsPDF not rendering as wanted

Tags: javascript, visualforce, jspdf

I'm totally new to javascript and I need to create a pdf from an a4 html page but this one is not rendering good. 
The problem is that it save only the last part of the html and it puts the margins of the html on top of the a4 pdf format.

[pdf version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6idgn.png)

As you can see in the image, the pdf saved takes only the end of the hmtl and does not fit the body to the a4 format. How should I do to solve this.

Here is the javascript function: `

```
function savePDF() {
             var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
 pdf.addHTML($('#someHtml')[0], function () {
     pdf.save('Test.pdf');
 });
            }
```

`

The html is something like a body with two pages inside.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You say want to create a a4 html page but in you you code you set it to letter. according to the `jsPDF` by default it's create A4 so can you try something like this :

```
function savePDF() {
        var pdf = new jsPDF();
        pdf.addHTML($('#someHtml')[0], function () {
        pdf.save('Test.pdf');
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it but it still give me the same strange result.